# Increment values is not working in Firestore using example code

Tags: vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

On this page of the documentation for Firestore, the supplied code does not work in my Vue project.

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value

Firestore is being used extensively in my Vue app. It's even being used on the same page I'm trying this on.

I am using VUE CLI 3, firebase 6.0.2, firebase-admin 8.0.0, vue 2.6.10.

```
var washingtonRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update({
    population: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(50)
});
```

The error message in the console says "firebase" is not defined. If I take out "firebase" it says "firestore" isn't defined.  If I take out "firestore" it says "FieldValue isn't defined".

Why doesn't it work?  I just want to add simple voting.

Comment: Where did you import `firebase`? You can't skip importing the library into your project where you use it.

Comment: it's being imported right at the start of the script section of the page.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the entire, minimal code that reproduces the problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example